# BroadcastReceiver with a Listener drains battery when not in use

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, battery

I have a receiver which waits for `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String theAction = intent.getAction();  
if (theAction != null && theAction.equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        CONTEXT = context;
        startListening();   
}
```

When it gets it, I register the listener (for orientation sensor):

```
public void startListening() {  
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) CONTEXT.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    if (sensors.size() > 0) {
        sensor = sensors.get(0);
        running = sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }
}
```

And then, in the Listener's `onSensorChanged()` method:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(running) {   
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        // do some not significant stuff here
    }
```

And now the problem: I get a phone call, receiver starts, then listener starts and everything works as designed. But, later on, when I look at the battery stats, my app is listed as the one with 2-3% of drain. *And* this percentage is increasing *even though* there are no calls - hence the receiver *is not* working.

Where does this battery drain come from? The activity which starts the receiver is not working (and it is single checkbox anyway). I suppose, that the listener may not get unregistered by `sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);`, but it shoudl work - I unregister the listener when it received the first event, it makes sense.

How could I solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where does this battery drain come from?

Never never never never never never never never have something in a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` live beyond `onReceive()`. IOW, you cannot safely register a `SensorListener` from a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`.

Please have your `BroadcastReceiver` delegate work to a `Service` (via `startService()`), where in `onStartCommand()` you register the `SensorListener`. When you get a sensor reading, or after a timeout (hint: phones don't always change orientation), or in `onDestroy()` (if Android decides to shut down your service), unregister the listener and call `stopSelf()` to shut down the service.

Comment: Nice solution. Not the best (still battery is used), but acceptable.

Comment: @jacek: Make sure your register/unregister calls line up for the sensor. I know that having a sensor active drains battery. It's possible that just the phone state listener will drain battery, though if that receiver is registered in the manifest, I would not have expected that behavior.

Comment: Maybe my phone's battery stats are crazy again. I would need to reset them, reset the phone, and start over. Or check on another device. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, I did the reset of the battery stats. Nothing helped. I Started my app 2 hours ago with fresh battery. Got one call (so one broadcast!) and my app was listed with 2% battery use. Fair enough. However, now my app is listed with 31% battery use! Where did I go wrong? I know, that if the receiver didn't get unregistered, I would have the "akmd" app on the list, because it manages the sensor I use. So the problem probably is not in the receiver itself.

Comment: Ok, I checked with ddms and it is clear, that sometimes the android.hardware.SensorManager$SensorThread doesn't get killed. Question is why - it get's killed but not always. And it drains the battery...

Comment: @jacek: The only reason I know for that thread to stick around is because you're not unregistering the `SensorListener`

Comment: I unregister it twice! First, in `onSensorChanged()`: `sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);` and second, in `onDestroy()` of the service `sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);`. Both methods get executed, but it seems that this unregistering doesn't work, at least not always... Strange.