# Implementing SensorEventListener in a BroadcastReceiver... is it possible?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-sensors

Why can't I have a class extending BroadcastReceiver and implementing SensorEventListener? This class receives alarm intents set in my application.

I have a class instance variable that is set inside the implemented onSensorChanged method. In the onReceive method I register the listener, have a while loop that runs until the class instance variable is set. After the loop I unregister the listener. But the variable is never set and the loop keeps running.

According to the answer here I should never register a listener inside a broadcast receiver:

[BroadcastReceiver with a Listener drains battery when not in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883664/broadcastreceiver-with-a-listener-drains-battery-when-not-in-use)

In AlarmManager docs there are all these warnings about the device sleeping but in my case it never sleeps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post:

[AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver instead of Service - is that bad ? (Timeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117350/alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-instead-of-service-is-that-bad-timeout-p?rq=1)

the onReceive method is run on the main application thread and cannot do a lot work or it times out. I can just fix my issue by moving the workload to an IntentService.